# Plotting graphs in Shiny R; using a repeat loop to plot data for automated analysis

Tags: r, plot, shiny, repeat, shinydashboard

**EDIT**

I am building a shiny app and one of the components of it would consist of automated data analysis. My main use for it would be to access an API to gather data and do subsequent analysis on it. This action occurs inside a `repeat` loop with a 5 minute delay (although this can be specified by the user of the app).  Once the delay is up, the API is accessed again and the process starts all over. This works well for me outside of shiny as I return my plots/tables as a list in the main console.

However, I am not able to execute it within a Shiny app. I cannot provide the API information but for all intents and purposes, here is a replicable example using the `mpg` data set.

Below is an example of a plot being generated using an action button and without the use of the repeat loop. Each time you click the action button, the graph will update with the current system time:

[image]

and the code that generates this:-

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui<-fluidPage(
  titlePanel('Minimal example'),
  tabsetPanel(
    
    tabPanel("Example",
             
             
             #summary
             sidebarPanel(width = 4, 
                          h5("The default interval for the analysis refresh is 5 minutes. If you wish to change this, please do so in the box below:"),
                          numericInput("intervaltime","Input refresh interval:",5),
                          br(),
                          h5("Press 'Run Analysis' button below to start automated analysis"),
                          actionButton("automatedanalysis", "Run Analysis")),
             mainPanel(
               h4("An example plot"),
               plotOutput("example_plot", width = "100%"),
               h4("Some text with updated system time"),
               textOutput("example_text")
             )
             
             
    )))



server<-function(input,output,session){
  
  
  observeEvent(input$automatedanalysis,{
    
    #interval=input$intervaltime*60
    #repeat{
    
      currenttime<-Sys.time()
      
      p<-ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + 
        geom_point()+ggtitle(paste0("graph made at: ",currenttime))# adds on the current time
      
    output$example_plot<-renderPlot({
      return(p)
    })
    
    
    output$example_text<-renderText({
      
      print(paste0("The current system time is: ", Sys.time())) #a check to know that it is working
      
    })

    #Sys.sleep(interval)
        
    #}
  })
  
  
}



shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, when I bring the repeat loop into action, with the interval timer which can be toggled using the numeric input in the UI, it no longer works. Here is the non-working code:-

```
ui<-fluidPage(
  titlePanel('Minimal example'),
  tabsetPanel(
    
    tabPanel("Example",
             
             
             #summary
             sidebarPanel(width = 4, 
                          h5("The default interval for the analysis refresh is 5 minutes. If you wish to change this, please do so in the box below:"),
                          numericInput("intervaltime","Input refresh interval:",5),
                          br(),
                          h5("Press 'Run Analysis' button below to start automated analysis"),
                          actionButton("automatedanalysis", "Run Analysis")),
             mainPanel(
               h4("An example plot"),
               plotOutput("example_plot", width = "100%"),
               h4("Some text with updated system time"),
               textOutput("example_text")
             )
             
             
    )))



server<-function(input,output,session){
  
  
  observeEvent(input$automatedanalysis,{
    
    interval=input$intervaltime*60
    repeat{
    
      currenttime<-Sys.time()
      
      p<-ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + 
        geom_point()+ggtitle(paste0("graph made at: ",currenttime))# adds on the current time
      
    output$example_plot<-renderPlot({
      return(p)
    })
    
    
    output$example_text<-renderText({
      
      print(paste0("The current system time is: ", Sys.time())) #a check to know that it is working
      
    })

    Sys.sleep(interval)
        
    }
  })
  
  
}



shinyApp(ui, server)
```

No graphs or textual outputs appear.

Once again, this works fine outside of a Shiny App, but I need this as a feature within the Shiny App I am developing.

In summary, how can I get this to work so that when the action button is clicked, the analysis refreshes after the end of the interval period?

Comment: Hi @Robin. Without a full repeatable script it is hard to help. Although you stated that the Shiny App uses some sensitive content, maybe you could generate some dummy data to work on?. I'm not sure of this but since you are using `repeat` inside an `observeEvent` call and objects created inside this are ephemeral and only shown on exit. I think your `repeat` call is never ending then ´observeEvent` never finish being unable to print your plots. Try using `reactiveValues` outside `observeEvent`.

Comment: Hi @BaltazarGonzálezChávez, I agree that it is difficult to help and normally I try to provide a reprex to help but not as viable in this case. The idea is that the action button ```automatedanalysis``` starts the automated analysis which then starts the ```repeat``` loop process. What you are saying makes sense in relation to the ```observeEvent```, however, when I wrap it in ```reactiveValues```,I get "Error in reactiveValues({ : All arguments passed to reactiveValues() must be named". Any idea why this is?

Comment: A more simplified question would be: is there any appropriate ways which use a repeat loop in shiny app to reproduce new plots in the UI? Is there any examples of this (from my searches so far, I haven't come up with much)? If i can get this to work then I can probably take my question from there.

Comment: Hi @BaltazarGonzálezChávez, I have updated the question to make it more friendlier and reproducible. I have also added a bounty. So feel free to have a look and see if you can solve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at the `invalidateLater` or `reactiveTimer` functions.

I'm using `invalidateLater` in the following example (**NOTE**: the function takes milliseconds as first argument).

You also shouldn't put any outputs inside an observer, make a `reactiveVal` / `reactiveValues` object and fill that at every new interval. You can use that object anywhere in the app then.

I also changed the `observeEvent` to a normal `observe`, since otherwise it would only trigger when the Button is clicked. Now, the observer triggers, when the Button is clicked, the interval slider is changed and when the interval has passed.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
ui<-fluidPage(
  titlePanel('Minimal example'),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Example",
             sidebarPanel(width = 4, 
                          h5("The default interval for the analysis refresh is 5 minutes. If you wish to change this, please do so in the box below:"),
                          numericInput("intervaltime","Input refresh interval:",5),
                          br(),
                          h5("Press 'Run Analysis' button below to start automated analysis"),
                          actionButton("automatedanalysis", "Run Analysis")),
             mainPanel(
               h4("An example plot"),
               plotOutput("example_plot", width = "100%"),
               h4("Some text with updated system time"),
               textOutput("example_text")
             )
    )))

server<-function(input,output,session){
  rv <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  observe({
    interval = input$intervaltime*1000
    invalidateLater(interval, session)
    req(input$automatedanalysis)
    print("Fill ReactiveVal")
    mpg$hwy <- mpg$hwy * runif(nrow(mpg))
    rv(mpg)
  })
  output$example_plot<-renderPlot({
    req(rv())
    currenttime<-Sys.time()
    print("Plot Code")
    ggplot(rv(), aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + 
      geom_point()+ggtitle(paste0("graph made at: ",currenttime))
  })
  output$example_text<-renderText({
    print(paste0("The current system time is: ", Sys.time())) #a check to know that it is working
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi @SeGa, thank you very much for having a look at this. I am going to try and augment this with my actual data set here and I will confirm whether it works in a couple of hours :)

Comment: This worked well, I made some minor tweaks but only in relation to my own data. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @SeGa, once again thank you for your solution, it works wonderfully! I was wondering if I could ask one more additional question. Since the analysis in this code is automated, I was thinking of adding in an extra ```actionButton``` which simply stops the automated analysis. I cant seem to find any relevant examples online and I was wondering if you could suggest something? Only if it's not too much trouble and it will be much appreciated :)

Comment: You could use the same actionButton and check with modulo 2 if the buttom is active or not. -> Putting `req(input$automatedanalysis %% 2 != 0)` before the `invalidateLater` part should work.

Comment: Hi SeGa, sorry it took me long to reply. This is great, thanks very much!